# SQL return 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two complicated select statements, each of which returns one value of the same type. I am trying to combine them into one statement which would work somewhat like UNION, only instead of returning 2 rows in one column it would return 2 distinctly named columns, each containing one of the values. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Yes, there is. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I tried Union and tried doing joins, which resulted in errors. Pretty stuck on this right now

Comment: @ nkj I don't have the statements with me, working from a different computer where I have it all saved, but they evaluate fine and return a string. I was wondering if there's a way to superficially combine them without going through and modifying each, as there is sorting involved for both according to different criteria.

Comment: @alex28 - The string "errors" is not an actual error message in any RDBMS. If you don't want this question to be closed (which can happen at any moment--as of this writing, four out of five votes to close have been cast), then **be more specific**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always do

```
SELECT (SELECT the_first_select) AS col1, (SELECT the_second_select) AS col2
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

```
select (select 'expr1'), (select 'expr2')
```